# Failed to sort primefaces' datatable on multi columns?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried to sort a datatable with two columns but failed.

I am working on primefaces7, I tried to sort a datatable with two columns but failed.

I followed the example on primefaces showcases: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml, set the value of sortMode to multiple, and also set two columns' sortby attributes.

After the application startup, each time I clicked any one of the two sort columns, the size of backend List SortMeta is 1, then I can only sort the datatable with one of the tow sort columns but not both of them.

xhtml code:

```
<p:dataTable var="hosp"
             binding = "#{hospitalController.sortTable}"
             value="#{hospitalController.hospitalLazyModel}"
             paginator="true"
             rows="7"
             paginatorPosition="bottom"
             paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
             currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} of {totalPages} pages, {totalRecords} records"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="7,15,30"
             lazy="true"
             id="sortTable"
             widgetVar="sortTable"
             sortMode="multiple"
             >

    <p:column headerText="Hospital Code" sortBy="#{hosp.hospitalId}">
        <h:outputText value="#{hosp.hospitalId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="HospitalName" sortBy="#{hosp.hospitalName}">
        <h:outputText value="#{hosp.hospitalName}" />
    </p:column>
```

backend code:

```
    public List<StdHospital> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        // here it always prints 1
        log.info("multiSortMeta size -> " + multiSortMeta.size());
```

I mean I can only get one sort info of the two columns through List SortMeta, however, since the type of the SortMeta on the backend is a List, why it does not contain the sort info of the two columns such as sort order and so on?

How to sort the datatable with both of the two columns?

Comment: If you do lazy loading, the sorting is completely up to you and in no way JSF or even PrimeFaces related. It is DB query or plain java sorting or... But not something PrimeFaces can help you with. [OptimusFaces](https://github.com/omnifaces/optimusfaces) is btw great for this.

Comment: @ Kukeltje, agree. But still I need the front end to pass in the sort order, right?

Comment: Do you press the MetaKey?

Comment: @Selaron, no, my keyboard does not have MetaKey.

Comment: See how important it is to ask the **right** question? You don't have a MetaKey? Normally for Windows/Linux it is the ctrl key, for apple the 'apple' key iirc for multi-sorting. Should be there on any keyboard.

Comment: For me it works holding down [ctrl]. But that's not the [Metakey as described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys). Not sure why they call it Metakey in the PF showcase. Does the Turkish keyboard possibly have one?

Comment: No idea (for me 'meta key' is one of  ctrl-alt-... but that seems to be not correct ;-) but you did not **try** the ctrl? Would have saved you (and us) lots of time ;-)

Comment: Er, its my embarrass. I really did not know what is at the first glance while saw Salaron's comment. After google I get the answer Meta key exists on MIT or MAC computer, and since my operation system is Windows, I replied there is no MataKey on my keyboard.

Comment: @Selaron: care to create an explicit answer just about the 'meta-key' actually being the ctrl (on windows?)

Comment: @Langston: I reverted your edit. Effectively that is a new question. Please create one.

Comment: @Kukeltje I did the close-vote for "typo/cant reproduce" because it's just a usage error - on the other hand this information might indeet possibly help a few future readers and the closing is not going to happen, so I added the answer as you suggested.

Comment: @Kukeltje, I raised another post, could you please have a look, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58850198/how-to-do-multi-column-sort-on-primefaces-datatable-without-pressing-ctrl-key

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation says](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/datatable?id=sorting):

> Multiple sorting is enabled by setting `sortMode` to `multiple`. In
>   this mode, clicking a sort column **while metakey is on** adds sort
>   column to the order group.

On Windows, this means **keeping the [ctrl]-Key pressed** while clicking the columns to sort by.
This may vary on different operating system, keyboard layout and input method (e.g. touch devices).

*Feel free to test on other OS/Input variants and edit it into the answer.*